# homestead.yaml file missing

Tags: laravel, homestead

I am trying to set up laravel homestead.

But after the following the instructions, still not able to set up.

When I run the bash init.sh from Homestead directory, it is not creating a homestead.yaml file.

I am on a Mac and I can see homestead.yaml is in the src/stubs folder but not in /Homestead folder even though after the running the bash init.sh is providing the success message saying "do you want to overwrite ..yaml" followed by "Homestead initialised". But still I don't see the yaml file in the homestead folder in my Mac.

My question is

1. Would init.sh copy the yaml file from src/stubs to Homestead folder or not?
2. Do I need to manually copy it?
   3.If I have to copy manually, why its asking to permission to overwrite when I run the init.sh command in the Homestead folder?

I am beginner to coding. So pls let me know if I am looking at the wrong places.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init.sh` will place `Homestead.yaml` in a hidden directory under your home directory `/Users/username/.homestead/` not  in `/Homestead`. Now To answer your questions:

1. Yes, `init.sh` will copy `Homestead.yaml` to `.homestead` directory along with after.sh and aliases.
2. You can copy it manually but you don't need to as `init.sh` should do that for you.
3. Because when you first ran init.sh, it created `.homestead` directory and placed the `Homestead.yaml` file in it, but when you run it again, It will find that there's a current `Homestead.yaml` and asks if it should overwrite it or not.

Comment: thanks for your response. Now when I tried to access the files from .homestead(hidden) directory, I seem to get an access denied error. Also still couldn't access the hidden files

Comment: Try changing the directory permissions to give yourself read/write access. Open a terminal and type `chmod -R 775 .homestead`.